# Set custom icon for file on Mac using Swift

Tags: swift, macos

In my application, I want to set a custom icon for a folder.
I am using the following code.

```
let path = "/Users/customUser/Desktop/test"
let icon = NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFile: "/Applications/Safari.app")
let res = NSWorkspace.shared.setIcon(icon, forFile: path, options: [])
print(res)
```

But it returns false

What am I doing wrong?
Or is there another way to change the icon of a file or folder?

Comment: Try turning off your app sandbox

Answer (score 1):

Mac apps are sandboxed by default, and only have write access to a small set of directories in their sandboxed. You are probably failing due to your app not having permission.

As I recall, if you have the user select the file with a file save dialog, that implicitly grants the app permission to write to the file.

Comment: Thank you. I saw that szhzhok only provides access to a few folders: including downloads. Tried to change the folder in the downloads. Can you tell me how can I select the desktop folder in open/save dialog?

Comment: I'm not clear one what you're asking. Are you asking about how to do that as a user, or how to code that in your app? Is your app sandboxed? Is it for you, or something you plan to put up on the app store? (For a personal app you can turn off sandboxing so your app has global file access.)

Comment: What is "szhzhok"?  Is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is a typo. I want write sandbox. This application will be allowed on the market. But when developing it, I would like to test all features before publishing

Comment: Sandboxed apps are not allowed to modify files unless the user grants permission. I suggest reading up on the app sandbox in Apple's developer documentation. It's been quite a while since I've looked at it, but my memory is that the file save dialog implicitly grants your app write permission to the file.

Comment: Thanks. Disconnecting the sandbox helped. As far as I understand, after publication, everything should also work without any additional permissions?

Comment: That is not correct. If you are trying to develop an app for the App Store you should develop it with sandboxing turned on. You will need to ask the user to grant permission to read/write any files outside of your app’s sandbox directories. I suggest reading up in Apple’s docs on the Mac App sandbox. This stuff is pretty well documented.